# ¿Cómo hacer un textArea con más control sobre el texto?

Tags: javascript, html, angular, textarea

Estoy trabajando en un proyecto con Angular 11.

Actualmente tengo una zona de *textArea* donde puedo escribir, pero es muy limitada en cuanto al diseño.
Necesito una zona donde pueda escribir y que me deje cambiar el color de X palabras, es decir, tengo una función creada que mientras escribes, analiza el texto y si reconoce un caracter de *@*, lo que hace es darle un formato en concreto, ya que interpreta que lo que estás introduciendo es una cuenta.

Esa función no la puedo usar en un *textArea* como tal, por que la posibilidad de diseño es muy limitada.

¿Cómo puedo solucionar esto?

En principio no pongo nada de mi código porque lo único que estoy usando aquí es un *textArea* normal y corriente, pero si necesitáis ver algo, lo añado gustosamente.

Comment: Hay librerías como [Monaco](https://www.npmjs.com/package/monaco-editor) que ofrecen este tipo de funcionalidades. El camino es no reinventar la rueda. Dicho esto, la pregunta en su formato actual puede terminar cerrada por ser muy amplia y tener esta tendencia a pedir opiniones o recursos externos.